# Was this line from Jurassic World ad libbed?

Tags: reference, jurassic-world, life-of-pi

In *Jurassic World*, Irrfan Khan's character Masrani [makes a reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ap-BMjHWTXs&t=34) to another character he played in *Life of Pi*:

> **MASRANI:**
>   So, how's my park doing?
>
> **CLAIRE:**
>   Great.
>
> **CLAIRE:**
>   We're up two and a half percent over last year, a bit lower than our initial projections--
>
> **MASRANI:**
>   No, no, no, how's it doing? Are the guests having fun? **Are the animals enjoying life?**
>
> **CLAIRE:**
>   Well, guest satisfaction is steady. In the low nineties. We don't have a way to measure the animals' emotional experience.
>
> **MASRANI:**
>   Sure you do. **You can see in their eyes...**

[*Life of Pi* quote:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCMPzZXNjUQ&t=45)

> **PI: Animals have souls. I have seen it in their eyes.**

Was this line ad libbed by the actor, or was the reference included by the script writers once Khan had been cast?

Comment: It's a common expression. I can't see this being specifically written to fit one actor when anyone would use it. You're over thinking this

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not the only person who noticed this, apparently: [IMDB Trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369610/trivia) `Irrfan Khan's character states that he can see an animal's happiness in its eyes. This is similar to what he says in Life of Pi (2012) where he plays an older version of the boy stuck on a raft with a tiger.`, [JURASSIC WORLD - Every Easter Egg & Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAi07z-B7IA), [Reddit discussion of quotes](https://www.reddit.com/r/JurassicPark/comments/3aj6ed/i_have_no_idea_why/) its TV Tropes page etc...

Comment: It this was some **non-common non-iconic** expression it would be different **but it's not**...it's a random generic line.